# Using a DLL developed on VS 2019 environment triggering crash when tried to launch an exe built in VS 2008 Environment

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2008, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I have a DLL that is developed in VS 2019 environment.

It has following Interface.

```
bool Initialize();
{
     // Do nothing
}
```

Interface declaration in DLL

```
extern "C" CDACVS19LIBRARY_API bool Initialize();
```

I uses the above Interface in one of the console exe created in VS2008 Environment as follows.

Initialize();

When I invoke this interface it is throwing below error

```
Run-time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'oss_' was corrupted.
```

What is wrong in the above code/approach?

There is something wrong about using a dll built in VS2019 environment in an exe developed in VS 2008 environment as we are using something built in later version in older version.

Is it not possible to do so? If possible, where I am not right in following the above approach?

**`If I use the same dll in a console exe built in 2019 environment, everything works just fine.`**

**EDIT** : Edited to make Interface declaration and definition proper.

Comment: How was the DLL compiled? Did you statically compile it?

Comment: It was compiled as a DLL. It is not a static library.

Comment: Yes, obviously... But how did you compile it? It would also be helpfull if you show some code.

Comment: What do you mean by how did I compile? Well I created a new DLL project in VS 2019. Declared interfaces for export. Defined them in source and then compiled and build in VS 2019. Platform ToolSet : Visual Studio 2019 (v142). C++ Lang Std ::Default (ISO C++14 Standard) .Please let me know what other compiler options you are looking at?

Comment: BTW did you decorate your definition of Initialize also with extern "C" ?

Comment: Yeah. Edited. I get a run time error when I launch that exe that uses DLL. So please assume it compiled fine

Comment: @engf-010 . No.

Comment: You must do that too !

Comment: @engf-010. Well I had tried that as well. Same results. Just that currently it doesn't have it. And the thing is, if I use the same dll in a console exe built in 2019 env, it works fine

Comment: In that case you're probably using compiler\STL-version specific data in your dll-intercace ! Stick to c-compatible data in your dll-interface.

Comment: Can you launch the process in a debugger (like WinDbg)?

Comment: This error is frequently the result of mismatching calling conventions. You aren't specifying a calling conventions, so you are relying on the compiler's default.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your declarations and defintions must match exactly.

Secondly ,if you want your DLL to be used by any program (no matter which compiler\language used) you must not use anything that could change by compilerversions in the DLL-interface. This means restrict your DLL-interface to C-compatible functionalities ,don't expose any STL-stuff or templates and do not rely on default calling-conventions for functions (decorate them as extern "C" or _cdecl). Write your interfaces as if your writing for C. Inside your DLL you do whatever you want.

Comment: Yeah, and probably declare both places with __stdcall or WINAPI (take your pick).